# What would be the cost of the season for a young tennis player?

Tags: tennis, finances

What would be **an estimate** of costs for a season for a young (15-18 years) tennis player who wants to play only in Europe circuit?

Excluding revenue (sponsors / prize), what about the costs: transfers, accommodation (2 * / 3 * hotels), equipment, tournaments, training

I hypothesize transfers of 2/3/4 tournaments each to be repeated 2 or 3 times during the year with a coach or a parent in tow